# Why cannot embed env vars into curl in Jenkins?

Tags: curl, jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins pipeline I cannot embed the env variables:

```
sh 'curl -d '{"color":"green","message":"${BUILD_NUMBER}","notify":false,"message_format":"text"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http:blahbah.com'
```

and the problem is even when I try to use escape chars \ in front of every ' and " the output on the target machine is always
${BUILD_NUMBER}

How should look the correct curl syntax here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `curl` `-d` argument command is surrounded with single-quotes.

```
curl -d '{"color":"green","message":"${BUILD_NUMBER}","notify":false,"message_format":"text"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http:blahbah.com'
```

In general (at least in `bash`) [*"Single quotes won't interpolate anything, but double quotes will (for example variables, backticks, certain \ escapes, etc...)"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781/627727).

With Jenkins Pipelines, you need to be careful about the quote escaping that is provided. You can see some of the strange behaviors documented [here](https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4).

One way to handle this case is to substitute the `env.BUILD_NUMBER` value in Groovy rather than at shell evaluation. Groovy's [triple-quoted strings](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_double_quoted_string) can also help with string quoting:

```
sh """curl -d '{"color":"green","message":"${env.BUILD_NUMBER}","notify":false,"message_format":"text"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http:blahbah.com'"""
```

Here I:

1. Surround the entire command with `"""`. Double quotes are used for [string interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation) and triple quotes are used to simplify the quoting inside for the `curl` command JSON.
2. `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` is Groovy interpolated into the JSON body

Comment: it doesn't work for me, is there any particular plugin needed?

Comment: `/tmp/jenkins8342961224735107425.sh: line 26: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}","description":"Hello: bad substitution
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Using `${BUILD_NUMBER}`, use `$BUILD_NUMBER`. It will do the trick. Here are some sample codes.

> Environment variables are accessible from Groovy code as env.VARNAME
>   or simply as VARNAME. You can write to such properties as well (only
>   using the env. prefix):
>
> ```
> env.MYTOOL_VERSION = '1.33'
> node {
>   sh '/usr/local/mytool-$MYTOOL_VERSION/bin/start'
> }
> ```

---

```
pipeline { 
  agent any 
  stages {
    stage('Build') { 
        steps { 
            sh 'echo "Hello World $BUILD_ID"' 
        }
    }
  }
}
```